# Choose grouping value based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to construct a query which meets the following criteria:

- select X columns and MAX(column1), group by X columns
- if column1 contains negative value (can be only one in given group), then instead of MAX(column1) display 'reset'

I know I can do it by using case before grouping and substituting negative values with a very large number and then using case after grouping, but this is an awfully messy solution.

Does anybody have a better idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can additionally select the minimum value and check that for negativity.
Something like the following:

```
select foo, case when min_value < 0 then 'reset' else to_char(max_value) end
from
(
  select foo, max(column1) as max_value, min(column1) as min_value
  from your_table
  group by foo
)
```

Or, without the sub query:

```
select foo, case when min(column1) < 0 then 'reset' else to_char(max(column1)) end
from your_table
group by foo
```

Comment: Could get away without the in-line view, even.

Comment: Wow, seems my brain doesn't work at it's best today... Thanks for the help.

Comment: The second query will throw `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER`, which can be fixed by changing `max(column1)` to `TO_CHAR(max(column1))`.

Comment: BTW, +1 for that second query nonetheless; my initial impulse was to do more like the first query but the second is much nicer.